# Adding values from a Map to an existing Source in Scala

Tags: scala, stream, akka, akka-stream

I am using akka streams. Can we add values from a map to an existing source in scala? I want to merge all the values from a `Future[Map[String, A]]` and a source of A `Source[A,_]` which are not already in the source. My method signature is:

```
case class A(id: String, someValue: String)
def addValuesToExistingSource(mySource: Source[A,_], myMapFuture: Future[Map[String, A]]): Source[A, _] = {
..//This is to be implemented
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the expected return type? Is the non duplicate a strong requirement? It would mean you have to consume the whole source to know what it contains to handle non duplicates (unless there's a magic operator in Akka Streams but I doubt it).

Comment: Added return type. Yes, its like consuming full source(which is apparently pretty less in size as per my current design) and return all the non duplicate elements in the map. I am trying to do a kind of right join on this.

Comment: Then why not use a `Seq` as return type?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
def addValuesToExistingSource(mySource: Source[A, _], myMapFuture: Future[Map[String, A]]): Source[A, _] = {
  //Change logic for values here
  val sf = Source.futureSource(myMapFuture.map(map => Source(map.values.toList)))
  Source.combine(mySource, sf)(Concat(_))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the keys of that map represent "ids" as in `A.id`. That would be much easier to understand if you'd introduce a typedef:

```
type Id = String
case class A(id: Id, someValue: String)
```

If I understood correctly, you want a source that first emits all `A`s from `mySource` and then (after `mySource` completed) emits all those values from the Map (from the Future) for which the key does not match any of the ids from the items of `mySource`?

**Approach one:** keep removing entries from the map and then emit the rest when `mySource` completes:

```
def addValuesToExistingSource(
    mySource: Source[A, _],
    myMap: Map[Id, A]
): Source[A, _] = {
  // map to Right and append a single Source that will signal that mySource completed
  val sourceWithCompleteItem: Source[Either[Unit, A], _] =
    mySource.map(a => Right(a)) ++ Source.single(Left(()))

  // use statefulMapConcat
  sourceWithCompleteItem.statefulMapConcat { () =>
    var remainingMap = myMap

    {
      case Right(a: A) =>
        // mySource emitted another item -> remove entry of same id from remainingMap
        remainingMap -= a.id
        // ...and emit the item to downstream
        Iterable(a)
      case Left(_) =>
        // mySource completed -> emit the remaining values from the map
        remainingMap.values
    }
  }
}

def addValuesToExistingSource(
    mySource: Source[A, _],
    myMapFuture: Future[Map[Id, A]]
): Source[A, _] = {
  Source
    .future(myMapFuture)
    .flatMapConcat(addValuesToExistingSource(mySource, _))
}
```

Obviously, this has the downside that nothing will be emitted before the future completes.

**Approach two:** accumulate a set of all ids that were emitted:

```
def addValuesToExistingSourceB(
    mySource: Source[A, _],
    myMapFuture: Future[Map[Id, A]]
): Source[A, _] = {

  // map to Right and append a single Source that will signal that mySource completed
  val sourceWithCompleteItem: Source[Either[Unit, A], _] =
    mySource.map(a => Right(a)) ++ Source.single(Left(()))

  // accumulator type for scan:
  case class ScanAcc(
      emittedIds: Set[Id] = Set.empty,
      isCompleted: Boolean = false,
      itemOpt: Option[A] = None
  )

  sourceWithCompleteItem
    .scan(ScanAcc()) {
      case (acc, Right(a)) =>
        ScanAcc(acc.emittedIds + a.id, isCompleted = false, Some(a))
      case (acc, Left(_)) =>
        ScanAcc(acc.emittedIds, isCompleted = true, None)
    }
    .flatMapConcat { scanAcc =>
      if (scanAcc.isCompleted) {
        Source
          .future(myMapFuture)
          .mapConcat(map => (map -- scanAcc.emittedIds).values)
      } else {
        scanAcc.itemOpt.fold[Source[A, _]](Source.empty)(Source.single)
      }
    }
}
```

This would emit before the future completes, but the downside is that you have this set in memory (which could become a problem depending how many items your source emits).

Here's that code with runnable examples: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/T6fd1tseTVmjGhcQfvoL0A